# How to change back to ascii code

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

I have converted ascii code as printable text

```
>>> ascii_string = 'some text \xbb \u4500'
>>> printable_text = ascii(ascii_string)
>>> printable_text[1:-1]# remove extra quotes
'some text \\xbb \\u4500'
>>> '\xbb' in 'some text \\xbb \\u4500' 
False
```

Now i want to change back as original text ('some text \xbb \u4500')
because i'm checking '\xbb' in ('some text \xbb \u4500') it return false value

[image]

Comment: bb is a number greater than 127 decimal so it isn't ascii

Comment: @JohnColeman: oh darn, I opened Python 2 by mistake and I couldn't find it.

Comment: Hmm... Now that I'm rereading this might not be quite a duplicate, given the extra quotes to be eliminated. `ast.literal_eval` would handle that though.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It is either unclear or a duplicate. Either way, closing it seems warranted.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks to respond,  yes i removed extra quotes, after i checking '\xbb' in ('some text \\xbb \\u4500') it return false value, i need to check  '\xbb' is present that text ('some text \\xbb \\u4500')

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare the string as raw (with `r` in front of it) and it will print all its characters as is:

```
>>> s = r'some text \xbb'
>>> print s
'some text \xbb'
```

Comment: Im reading data from xls , how should i add it r  in front  of it string ?

Comment: Im checking '\xbb' in  (r'some text \xbb'), it gives false value